# Error "Could not find or load main class com.example.NodeDriver"

Tags: corda

I got a error:

> Could not find or load main class com.example.NodeDriver

after run Example cordapp java by intellij .

Comment: Answer to the problem is present in the following link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717001/error-class-com-example-nodedriverkt-not-found-in-module-cordapp-example

Answer (score 3):

This is an IntelliJ caching issue. Try clearing IntelliJ's cache and restarting IntelliJ, or deleting and recreating the run configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue, I tried invalidate cache and restart but doesn't help. any other ideas?