# Problems running example-cordapp via intellij on fresh build (windows 10)

Tags: kotlin, corda

I can't seem to get a clean build of example-cordapp to run.

I am following the following tutorial:
https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-cordapp.html#opening-the-example-cordapp-in-intellij

After the gradle build runs I get the following warning (unsure if related):

`Duplicate content roots detected: Path [C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/CordaProjects/samples/cordapp-example/config/dev] of module [cordapp-example.clients.main] was removed from modules [cordapp-example.workflows-java.main, cordapp-example.workflows-kotlin.main]`

I then keep getting the following error when I attempt to run the "Run Example Cordapp" configuration, pressing the green arrow just as instructed.
It brings up a window that asks me to specify the module. I use cordapp-example, but it produces the following error:

`Class 'com.example.test.NodeDriverKt' not found in module cordapp-example`

I have already done a clean rebuild of Java, Intellij, and I have recloned the repo. I'm not sure where to go from here. I followed the tutorial exactly.

I have also attempted the advice given here, only to get the same error:
[error Class 'com.example.NodeDriverKt' not found in module 'cordapp-example'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49717001/error-class-com-example-nodedriverkt-not-found-in-module-cordapp-example)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please change the code in following file 
samples/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/com/example/test/NodeDriver.kt
Hope it works for you

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = User("user1", "test", permissions = setOf("ALL"))
    driver(DriverParameters(waitForAllNodesToFinish = true)) {
        val nodeFutures = listOf(
                startNode(
                        providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"),
                        customOverrides = mapOf("rpcSettings.address" to "localhost:10008", "rpcSettings.adminAddress" to "localhost:10048", "webAddress" to "localhost:10009"),
                        rpcUsers = listOf(user)),
                startNode(
                        providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"),
                        customOverrides = mapOf("rpcSettings.address" to "localhost:10011", "rpcSettings.adminAddress" to "localhost:10051", "webAddress" to "localhost:10012"),
                        rpcUsers = listOf(user)),
                startNode(
                        providedName = CordaX500Name("PartyC", "Paris", "FR"),
                        customOverrides = mapOf("rpcSettings.address" to "localhost:10014", "rpcSettings.adminAddress" to "localhost:10054", "webAddress" to "localhost:10015"),
                        rpcUsers = listOf(user)))

        val (nodeA, nodeB, nodeC) = nodeFutures.map { it.getOrThrow() }

        startWebserver(nodeA)
        startWebserver(nodeB)
        startWebserver(nodeC)
    }
```